# Hook into TYPO3 form creation

Tags: forms, typo3, hook

I'm looking for a hook to hook into the creation of a frontend form in TYPO3 (e.g. a contact form) which will allow me to pass the form structure to my extensions the moment a form is created (or edited).

I'm not so sure where to look, and I have asked before, but might have formulated my question unclear. Does anyone know if such a hook exists, or is available in the new formengine of TYPO3 8?

Or if you have a better solution I could use, I'm open for everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe what you intend to do?
What do you mean by "passing the form structure"?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "new formengine"? The form engine is used in the TYPO3 backend. The new "form framework" generates forms for the frontend. The hooks are documented: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#runtime-manipulation.